# Mac - Xcode Supposedly Updated But Version Did Not Change

Tags: xcode, macos, mac-app-store

Okay this is the second time this has happened to me. I updated `Xcode` to version 7.3.1 from the `Mac App Store`, which took FOREVER. After the update finished, the version number remained at 7.2 even though the `Updates` section of the `App Store` shows `Xcode` 7.3.1 as a recent download.

This is a big problem because I can't run my app on my iPhone because I keep getting the "Could not find developer disk image" error since `Xcode` is not updated to the most recent version.

I can no longer "update" `Xcode` again since it's no longer in the `Software Updates` section in the `App Store`.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Comment: @jtbandes So do I just uninstall `Xcode` and reinstall from this link? Or will the `Xcode` 7.3.1 download from this link automatically update my `Xcode` version?

Comment: I think this could work: Delete the XCode application, open App Store, go to the "Purchased" tab, find XCode there, and install.

Comment: It won't replace it automatically. It doesn't really matter if you uninstall. Xcode is just a .app. You can even have multiple versions.